# FMU Compliance Checker: FMICAPI: undefined symbol: va_start (Linux)

Tags: linux, fmi

In an FMI wrapper, we use a variadic function for logging. When running the FMU compliance checker (2.0.3) for linux64 on an FMU (for Co-Sim) compiled with gcc 4.9.2, the compliance checker throws an error when loading the *.so file:

```
[FATAL][FMICAPI] Could not load the DLL: /tmp/fmucktmpslmDuk/binaries/linux64/Frame.so: undefined symbol: va_start
```

I'm wondering if it is forbidden to use [va_start](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdarg/va_start/) in FMI in Linux? The FMI specifications ([1](https://svn.modelica.org/fmi/branches/public/specifications/v1.0/FMI_for_CoSimulation_v1.0.pdf), [2](https://svn.modelica.org/fmi/branches/public/specifications/v2.0/FMI_for_ModelExchange_and_CoSimulation_v2.0.pdf)) do not seem to give a hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just

```
#include <stdarg.h>
```

`va_arg` and many others are defined there.